# Не работает Collision в Particle System?

Tags: unity3d

Не работает ни вариант с Planes ни с collision mode  -> World ->3d - частицы просто пролетают.

Answer (score 0):

Вы с чем пытаетесь получить коллизию? Коллизия World 3D не работает с MeshCollider, если на ней нет галочки convex. Также вариант Planes и world 2D не будет работает с коллайдерами 3D размерности